# Images looks faded on Hover

Tags: html, css

I've got two images, that when you hover the other image should show, and show brighter.

For some reason, the image (in .top-1-1) looks more faded when you hover the mouse over it.

How to fix this?

HTML

```
 <div class="top-1-1"><a href="experiences.aspx">
       <img src="images/myexperience.png" width="111" height="23" alt="My Experience" /></a>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.top-1-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 111px;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    background :url("../images/myexperience-on.png") no-repeat;

}

.top-1-1 a, .nav a:link, .nav a:visited {
  display:block;
  width: 111px;
  height: 23px; 
}

.top-1-1 a:hover img {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Nbkda/

Comment: The background images might be different opacity.

Comment: 1 image in the html.  1 in the CSS.  The CSS image replaces the html images on hover.  Problem is the hover image looks faded.  and it's not if you look at it in photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem once in IE with a png image. Is it with all browsers? If so, it might be as Ennui said with transparency in the image. Maybe turn it into a jpeg if transparency isn't a requirement. Also, is javascript a possibility? Then you can get rid of some of that CSS.

```
<div class="top-1-1"><a href="experiences.aspx">

<img onmouseover="this.src='images/myexperience-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/myexperience.png'" src="images/myexperience.png" width="111" height="23" alt="My Experience" /></a>

</div>
```

also, with the above, Where is the beginning of the 'a' tag? I only see the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have an `img` with the `background` attribute in CSS. Try to use some Javascript instead the CSS.

You can take a look at this ecause it can offer you more than my answer http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: how to, any example on what you mean?

Comment: You have to create event handlers for MouseEnter and Leave, in those event handlers change the SRC of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this is that the hover state image (myexperience-on.png) has some transparency in it.  Try adding a background color to the css:

```
background: #FFF url("../images/myexperience-on.png") no-repeat;
```

or

```
background: #000 url("../images/myexperience-on.png") no-repeat;
```

Or you could edit the image and either convert it to jpg (no transparency) or add a layer with a solid background color behind it to make sure.

If not that then I am not sure what the issue would be and it may have to do with some javascript or other CSS on your site that is affecting the elements in question.  Do you have a link to the site?

This is a pretty odd way to go about making a rollover though - why not make the A tag a block level element and have its background set to the default image and the hover to the :hover psuedoclass?